# Fetch dos filhos com JPA+Hibernate não está funcionando

Tags: java, hibernate, jpa

Tenho duas classes, `Terminal` (que é o pai) e `Portaria` (filho).

Estou usando *JPA* e está funcionando, mas tem um bug que não consigo resolver.

Eu carrego uma lista de `Terminal` e ao testar o `t.getPortarias()` ele está instanciado e mostrando os filhos para os que possuem e mostrando size 0 para os que não possuem filhos, até aí tudo certo.

Daí eu crio um novo `Terminal`, este novo objeto não instancia o `t.getPortarias()` fica como `null`, os outros objetos estão lá com os filhos, mas o objeto novo não. Se eu fechar o sistema e abrir novamente aí o objeto novo aparece com o filho instanciado.

O problema é que dá `NullPointerException` quando testo `t.getPortarias().isEmpty()` porque não está carregando o objeto filho quando eu dou um `persist` no objeto.

Já tentei usar manager diferente em cada DAO, já tentei usar o mesmo e também não deu.
Já coloquei como *lazy* e *eager* o *fetch* e também não deu certo.

### Classe Terminal

```java
@Entity
public class Terminal implements Serializable {
    @Id
    @GeneratedValue
    private int terminalId;

    @Column(nullable = false, unique = true)
    private String nome;

    @Column(nullable = false, unique = true)
    private String cnpj;

    @Column(nullable = false)
    private String endereco;

    @Lob
    private byte[] logo;

    @OneToMany(mappedBy = "terminal")
    private List<Portaria> portarias;
```

### Classe Portaria

```java
@Entity
public class Portaria implements Serializable {
    @Id
    @GeneratedValue
    private int portariaId;

    @Column(nullable = false)
    private String descricao;

    @ManyToOne
    @JoinColumn(name = "terminalId", nullable = false)
    private Terminal terminal;
```

Nesse trecho eu testo se posso excluir ou não, mas dá pau porque o `List` do `getPortarias` nem foi instanciado:

```java
public boolean canDelete(Terminal t) throws BusinessException {
    if (!t.getPortarias().isEmpty()) {
        throw new BusinessException("Não é possível excluir porque existe portarias associadas a este terminal");
    }
    return true;
}
```

Nesse trecho eu pego o objeto pelo `id` para excluir:

```java
public T getById(int id) {
    return getDbManager().find(entityClass, id);
}
```

Como faço para o fetch dos filhos funcionar?

Comment: *"Daí eu crio um novo Terminal, este novo objeto não instancia o t.getPortarias()"*. Você identificou a parte do código com problema e não postou justamente esta parte. Mostre este código que pois parece relevante na sua questão.

Comment: @Caffé primeiro eu carrego um jTable com a lista de Terminais, quando a pessoa selecionar uma linha, eu pego o id do registro e carrego um objeto com `em.find(Terminal.class, id)` e mando pro `canDelete` que é onde dá erro no `t.getPortarias().isEmpty()`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Resumindo os comentários em uma resposta.
Você caiu em um problema comum com relações bidirecionais.

Segue um [enxerto do Wikibooks](http://en.wikibooks.org/wiki/Java_Persistence/Relationships#Common_Problems)

> **Object corruption, one side of the relationship is not updated after updating the other side**
>
> A common problem with bi-directional relationships is the application updates one side of the relationship, but the other side does not get updated, and becomes out of sync. In JPA, as in Java in general, it is the responsibility of the application or the object model to maintain relationships. If your application adds to one side of a relationship, then it must add to the other side.

Fazendo uma tradução livre:

> **Corrupção de objeto, um lado do relacionamento não é atualizado após atualizar o outro lado**
>
> Um problema comum com relacionamentos bidirecionais é quando a aplicação atualiza um lado do relacionamento, porém o outro lado não é atualizado, ficando fora de sincronia. No JPA, como em Java em geral, **é responsabilidade da aplicação ou do modelo de objetos manter os relacionamentos** (enfase minha). Se sua aplicação adiciona a um lado do relacionamento, então ele deve adicionar ao outro lado.

Em suma, quando você persiste um objeto com o seu provedor JPA ele passa a existir no contexto de persistência. Pense no contexto de persistência como uma área de memória com os objetos que você está manipulando; o contexto de persistência está entre a aplicação e o banco de dados.

Quando você persiste um `Terminal` ele passa a fazer parte do seu contexto de persistência. Quando você persiste as diversas `Portarias` com uma referência a esse `Terminal` elas também passam a fazer parte do contexto de persistência.

Eventualmente o seu provedor vai escrever o estado do contexto de persistência no banco, ou seja, executar operações de `insert`, `delete`, `update`, etc.

No seu caso, se você apenas associar o `Terminal` à `Portaria`, do lado do banco de dados tudo ocorrerá corretamente. Como a `fk` está na tabela `portaria`, associar apenas o `Terminal` à portaria é o suficiente para que a `fk` seja inserida corretamente.

O mesmo não ocorre com o objeto `Terminal` presente no contexto de persistência. O objeto `Terminal` administrado por ele não tem como saber que novas `Portarias` relacionadas a ele foram persistidas a não ser que você faça isso explicitamente.

### Soluções

#### 1. Manipule os dois lados do relacionamento explicitamente

Esqueça o que você conhece sobre banco de dados. Se você fosse atualizar um modelo orientado a objetos sem o auxílio de ferramentas acabaria tendo que atualizar ambos os lados do relacionamento:

```
portaria.setTerminal(terminal);
terminal.getPortarias().add(portaria);
```

#### 2. Deixe que seu modelo cuide disso.

Podemos enriquecer o domínio para lidar com relações bidirecionais:

```
class Terminal {

    // ...

    @OneToMany(mappedBy = "terminal")
    private List<Portaria> portarias;

    public void adicionarPortaria(Portaria p) {
        this.portariais.add(p);
        if (portaria.getTerminal() != this) {
            portaria.setTerminal(this);
        }
    }

    // ...
}
```

E na classe `Portaria`:

```
class Portaria {

    // ...

    @ManyToOne
    @JoinColumn(name = "terminalId", nullable = false)
    private Terminal terminal;

    public void setTerminal(Terminal t) {
        this.terminal = t;
        if (!t.getPortarias().contains(this)) {
            t.getPortarias().add(this);
        }
    }

    // ...
}
```

#### 3. Assuma que o contexto de persistência foi corrompido, busque as informações do banco.

Foi isso que fizemos com o método `refresh`:

```
entityManager.persist(portaria);
entityManager.refresh(terminal);
```

Basicamente o que estamos fazendo aqui é dizer para o provedor JPA: "Persista a nova portaria (com a `fk` para terminal`) e "refresque" o conteúdo do terminal conforme o que foi persistido no banco".

Essa aparentemente é a mais simples das soluções, porém é também a menos recomendável devido a uma série de problemas:

1. São feitos `selects` desnecessários.
2. O provedor JPA está livre para "reordenar" as operações da maneira que bem entender, bem como atrasar a escrita no banco. De forma que nem sempre podemos contar com o estado do banco.
3. Em certos ambientes existe um segundo nível de cache. Nesses ambientes você pode acabar recuperando um objeto corrompido do cache, tendo a necessidade de desalojar (`evict`) do cache antes de refrescar o estado.

#### 4. Evitar relacionamentos bidirecionais

Essa é uma máxima comum entre desenvolvedores mais experientes. Nem sempre precisamos de  relacionamentos bidirecionais. Quando possível vale a pena simplificar o modelo. Você realmente precisa navegar tanto de `Terminal` para suas `Portarias` quanto de uma `Portaria` de volta para o `Terminal`? A complexidade de introduzir um relacionamento bidirecional realmente compensa se comparada a complexidade de fazer consultas customizadas para buscar o outro lado? Esses são questionamentos justos que devem ser feitos antes de introduzir um relacionamento bidirecional.